# Numpy array display different results than the file that was used to create it

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a file which I had converted into an array.
File looks like this:

[image]

When I print results I get these values:

```
# Example A

a=gift_costs
print(a)

[ 8 84 42 ... 59 12 12]


# Example B

b=gift_costs[gift_costs]
print(b)

[78 48 92 ... 80 23 23]
```

Example A prints the good results. But Example B no. Why? What do I have to google to know the answer?

Comment: How did you create `gift_costs`, the array?  How much of the basic numpy introduction have you read?  What do you understand about array dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing array `a` (it's also `gift_costs`) with itself, *i.e.* the resulting array `b` would be characterized by this loop:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   b[i] = a[a[i]]
```

Comment: ok. I was trying to find all values lesser than 25 without using a loop. ```print(gift_costs[gift_costs < 25])```  When printing, it seems everything is fine: ```[ 8 23 22 ... 18 12 12]```